# importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for djoser pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, djoser, python-exec, django-react

### Context

I made a Django react app. Now I want to make it a desktop application so that the user does not have type `python manage.py runserver` and also activate the environment every time. I used pyinstaller. I did all the steps mentioned for [django](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Executable-From-Django).

### Problem

when I run my executable file made from pyinstaller, I got this error

```
File "manage.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "djoser\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 955, in version
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 928, in distribution
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 518, in from_name
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for djoser
[2200] Failed to execute script 'manage' due to unhandled exception!
```

### What I have done

I have already installed Djoser in the environment and the environment is also activated. I have also tried to add in manage.py file and also in hidden_import lists but nothing changed. I have also tried adding `--copy-meta=djoser`  in the build command but it got even worse error.

How do I fix this error and If there are any better alternative solutions out there? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found for myself another solution . To run this django file by creating a batch file

```
@echo off

set "VENV_NAME=myenv"
set "PROJECT_DIR=C:\path\to\project"

cd /d %~dp0

cd /d %PROJECT_DIR%

call "%VENV_NAME%\Scripts\activate.bat"

python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

manage.exe runserver --norelaod